# How to use big integers in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

How can I make a large integer in AppleScript? I suppose there is a certain byte limit which doesn't allow me to work with enormous numbers.

Is there any way around this except for using a float?

Comment: How large is very large? Applescript moves to scientific notation for very large numbers, so you do run out of significant figures. e.g. set test to 2147483647  as integer
tell me
 test * 2
end tell gives 4.294967294E+9

Comment: i found this, but it's above my pay-grade... http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=36635